# Attach FormControl to another Control in a ValueControlAccessor - do or don't

Tags: angular

I found a blog post by Christian Lüdemann - [Form validation with ControlValueAccessor](https://christianlydemann.com/form-validation-with-controlvalueaccessor/) where the FormControl of the injected `NgControl` is bound to a FormControl in the template:

```js
//...
    public formControl = new FormControl('');
//...
    constructor(public ngControl: NgControl) {
        ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
    public ngAfterViewInit(): void {
        // syncing with validators on host element
        this.formControl = this.ngControl.control as FormControl;
    }
//...
```

This works but I am not sure, whether this should be done or not. Is this the way to go or should I do something else to "sync" the validators?

BTW - the Validators get called twice that way.

Answer (score 1):

From the information you provided in your question, I see no reason to assign `this.ngControl.control` to the control you have initialized at the top of your file.

The only reason you would get a reference of the control from the injected `NgControl` would be if you wanted to add or replace validators that the parent form must listen to, like this:

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    const control = this.ngControl.control;
    const validators = control.validator
      ? [control.validator, this.allRequiredFieldsFilled]
      : this.allRequiredFieldsFilled;
    control.addValidators(validators);
    control.updateValueAndValidity();
}
```

But again, you wouldn't need to reassign. I hope this answers your question.

On another note, consider annotating the injected `NgControl` with the `@Self()` decorator. I explain why in [this article](https://javascript.plainenglish.io/angular-custom-form-controls-nested-form-groups-made-easy-2ac09e91cf67) about custom form components.

Comment: Sorry, but the question was how sync the error state from the injected control to the control in my component with `ControlValueAccessor`.

I do not think the Validator interface itself will help me here. Or is there any trick?

Comment: @KirillGordineRhenag Hey! Yeah, you're right! My bad. I've edited my answer. Since you're injecting `NgControl` you need to set up value accessor and validators. You've done the first part correctly. I included a snippet in my answer on how to do the latter. You can assign any validator this way. Hope this helps.

Comment: unfortunately the new answer does not answer my question, too. The component should not validate. The question is about the magic applied in `ngAfterViewInit`:
`this.formControl = this.ngControl.control as FormControl;`
which do the job but I am not sure whether this is not to dirty to be used.

Comment: @KirillGordineRhenag So your concern is about assigning it to `this.formControl`? Can you also include the respective template html file in your post?

Comment: @KirillGordineRhenag I've edited my answer again. Hopefully, this time it covers your question.